# How to stick a data series to x-axis of HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a series for highcharts. Which needs to stick to the x-axis.

Let me know if its possible.

EDIT:

Sticking to X-axis is solved. But I am struck in getting Date and time in X-axis.

I have date in Format:
 "2015-10-01 19:13:45", 
"2015-10-18 00:00:00",
"2015-11-17 00:00:00",

Want to show x-axis in following format:

11:00 EST   11:10 EST  11:15 EST  11:20 EST  11:25 EST  11:30 EST  11:35 EST etc

My Code for HighChart is as follows: [HighCharts code](http://jsfiddle.net/AkashPathak/Lmyqom1u/1/)

```
Code
```

Comment: if the values throughout the series are same it will automatically stick to xAxis. you can post your code it would be easy to understand the problem

Comment: Hi,
I have date in  "date": "2015-10-18 00:00:00", format. Don't know how to format it for HighCharts.

Comment: use date.utc(2015-10-18 00:00:00)   in highchart directly or write a function to get timestamp using javascript(covert it to date object and then getTime)

Comment: date.utc(2015-10-18 00:00:00) doesn't worked in my case. Can we get date formatted by momentJs.

Comment: yes , moment.js could be used

Comment: @AkashPathak Please post live example, like JSFiddle, or at very least used code and chart's configuration. To be honest, your image is not very helpful. Exemplary data will be also appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you need to be specific about what you're having trouble with, and what you've tried to do so far.

Answer (score 0):

Dates needs to be parsed into JavaScript timestamp, because this is the only accepted format for `datetime` type axis in Highcharts. More info in [Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8otqjh6d/

To change format of displayed axis' labels and/or tooltip you could use formatters (for [tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and [axis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter)) or dateTimeLabelFormats (for[tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.date) and [axis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats))